# Will Installing VC Express 2008 on a VS2008-ready machine corrupt my system?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on my machine and I want to know whether I can install VC Express 2008 with no crashes. What would I want such a thing? tutorials.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely supported scenario and should present no issues for you.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm more confident to give it a try. I'll be posting the results.